# Guidance: how to view de-compressed gzipped XML data in HTTP body

Tags: http, networking, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

We have a server that sends an HTTP Post response to my client, and the body of this POST response is an XML data that has been gzipped.

In Wireshark, we can view the original XML data by following the HTTP stream. However, I was wondering if it's possible to view the decompressed XML fields directly in the Details Panel under the Media Type subtree. (In the screenshot, notice how Media Type only shows `Media type: application/gzip (28040)`).

To do this, I'm wondering whether to:

1. Write a subdissector to handle only HTTP bodies. However, it doesn't seem possible to get the original http dissector to call this subdissector
2. Write a dissector that wraps over the original dissector. However, this requires reassembling HTTP
3. Is there some hidden feature for Wireshark to automatically decompress and show the xml data?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample capture file somewhere?  Glancing at the source code for the XML and HTTP dissectors, it seems the XML dissector does register as a heuristic dissector and that the HTTP dissector should attempt to pass off dissection to be claimed as XML, but for some reason that's not happening and it's not obvious why.  As a possible work-around, the XML dissector does have a port preference, so you could add the relevant TCP port there and the HTTP dissector should hand off dissection to it unconditionally.  Not ideal if it's port 80 but it might help here?

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware an XML dissector existed. The proper question then should be: why isn't the XML dissector being called? It turned out the solution was to change the Content-Type to text/xml, after which the XML data showed up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creds goes to [Christopher Maynard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2755698/christopher-maynard) for suggesting this.

The problem happens because the XML subdissector isn't being called by the HTTP dissector. To get the HTTP dissector to call it, change the Content-Type header from application/gzip to text/xml.